# sql custom select

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Could anybody please help me with query

Lets say my table table has rows like 1,2,3,4,5,......50k
I would like to select rows likely 1,3,5,....49997,49999 or 1,4,7...49997
 Pls help me how to achieve this in sql and as well as in linq
Thank you

Comment: Please show a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL Server/MySQL/Postgresql/SQLite` version using modulo division:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE id % 2 = 1;

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE id % 3 = 1;
```

As [`jarlh`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) mentioned in comment there is `MOD(id, x)` operator in standard SQL (not working in `SQL Server/SQLite`)

Comment: And ANSI/ISO SQL answer has MOD(id, 2) etc.